# Keep track of installed pwa instances

Tags: progressive-web-apps

We want to keep track of each pwa installation for a user. So we could track notifications, like did every instance of the app user installed (pc or phone, or ff, or chrome) have received the update. Can we know the pwa instance was uninstalled? Can we know web push was delivered to every instance?

Answer (score 0):

In your service worker, fire a http post to your server in the "install" event.  You'll need to get your userID from indexdb or similar.  Use "fetch" not xmlhttp the service worker.

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
            console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');
            var rc = cache.addAll(filesToCache);
            postServerStatus( "installcomplete" );
            return rc;
        })
    );
});

function postServerStatus( strStatus ) {
    var strUserID = "getfromindexdb";
    fetch('./datasvc.aspx', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            service: strStatus,
            userid: strUserID
        }),
     });
}
```